# Setting the Value of a Long and the Time on a Date to Midnight

Tags: javascript, date

All, I am trying to set the time component of a order. The `OrderDate` field is defined as follows

```
{
    "OrderDate" : {
        "DateTime" : ISODate("2017-11-29T00:00:00.000+00:00"),
        "Ticks" : 636475104000000000
    }
}
```

I wish to update an `OrderDate` that has a non-zero time component, to have a time components of 00:00:00.000+00:00. The order I wish to change looks like

```
{
    "OrderDate" : {
        "DateTime" : ISODate("2020-04-17T01:52:14.280+01:00"),
        "Ticks" : 637226815342800000
    }
}
```

I want this too look like

```
"OrderDate" : {
    "DateTime" : ISODate("2020-04-17T00:00:00.000+00:00"),
    "Ticks" : 636475104000000000
}
```

The function I am attempting to use is

```
function (order) 
{
    const midnightTime = new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    print("midnightTime = " , midnightTime.toLocaleString());
    print("orderTime = " , order.OrderDate.DateTime.toLocaleString());

    order.OrderDate.DateTime = new Date(
        order.OrderDate.DateTime.getFullYear(), 
        order.OrderDate.DateTime.getMonth(), 
        order.OrderDate.DateTime.getDay(),
        0, 
        0,
        0, 
        0);
    print("orderTime = " , order.OrderDate.DateTime.toLocaleString());

    //order.OrderDate.Ticks = NumberLong(636475104000000000);
    db.Orders.save(order);
}
```

The output of this is

- midnightTime =  31/12/1899, 00:00:00
- marketOrderTime =  17/04/2020, 01:52:14
- marketOrderTime =  05/04/2020, 00:00:00

Q1. Why do I get 05/04/2020 here and not *17*/04/2020, 00:00:00 and how can I correct this?
Q2. When I uncomment the setting of the ticks, I get

> "message" : "Cannot set property 'Ticks' of null",   "stack" :
>   "script:27:45" +
>               "script:28:91" +
>               "script:28:91" +
>               "script:9:7"

how can I set the Tick value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a legacy "feature" of ECMAScript that year values 0 to 99 are treated as 1900 to 1999, so `new Date(0, 0, 1)` creates a Date for 1900-01-01.

If *orderDate.DateTime* is a Date instance, then to set the UTC time to zero just do:

```
orderDate.DateTime.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
```

> Q1. Why do I get 05/04/2020 here and not 17/04/2020, 00:00:00

Because you're creating the date using *getDay*, which returns the day of the week numbered 0 to 6 for Sunday to Saturday. You should be using *getDate* instead.

However, the original date is UTC, so you should use UTC methods:

```
order.OrderDate.DateTime = new Date(
    order.OrderDate.DateTime.getUTCFullYear(), 
    order.OrderDate.DateTime.getUTCMonth(), 
    order.OrderDate.DateTime.getUTCDate());
```

Missing values are treated as zero (except for date, which is 1). But just set the time to zero as shown above.

> Q2. When I uncomment the setting of the ticks, I get…

The message is telling you that `order.OrderDate` is null. Try

```
console.log(typeof order.OrderDate)
```

You need to post a runnable snippet demonstrating that.

What is "NumberLong"? Perhaps you're looking for [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt/BigInt)?